# Doesn't work th SqlCommand with multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

With one `SELECT` query, the code seems to add to the listbox correctly, but when I add another query, the listbox doesn't show anything anymore, and it seems that  that `rdr[3]` does not exists (Contact has 3 columns and `Numar_contact` has one column (should't it be this one the `rdr[3]`?))

```
string connString = @"database=Agenda_db; Data Source=Marian-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Persist Security Info=false; Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

try {
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Contact;"+ "SELECT * FROM Numar_contact", conn)

   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
       listBox1.Items.Add(rdr[0].ToString() + ' ' + rdr[1].ToString() + ' ' + rdr[2].ToString()+' '+ rdr[3].ToString());
   }

   rdr.Close();
```

Comment: You should know what's in rdr[index]. Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: You should also add in `using` blocks to dispose properly of your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: So `Contact` has 3 columns and `Numar_contact` has one column, and you are expecting one result with 4 columns? Correct? If that is so, how does a row in `Contact` get associated with a row in `Numar_contact`? Or are you doing a cross apply. Please include in your question the actual schema for the two tables.

Comment: For the moment, the two tables have no relation between them; can't I just put in one result 3 columns from a table with one column from another table, with the same number of rows?

Comment: if you can not understand how to create a UNION query then look at this simple straight forward example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677318/how-to-run-multiple-sql-command-in-single-sql-connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join your queries with a `UNION`. The way you've got it now, it'll return two results sets.

```
SELECT [col1], [col2] FROM Contact
UNION ALL
SELECT [col1], [col2] FROM Numar_contact
```

As DJ KRAZE pointed out in a comment, it might not be a bad idea to wrap this in a sproc or a TVF. But this will work too.

**Edit:**

I just learned via comments that the two tables are actually unrelated. In light of that, I'd be tempted to use two `SqlCommand`s with two, distinct `foreach` loops. But if you're sold on this way,

```
SELECT id_contact, nume_contact, prenume_contact FROM Contact
UNION ALL
SELECT id_contact, numar, NULL FROM Numar_contact
```

This will align the data from the two tables, but where the second table doesn't have a `[prenume_contact]` it will select `NULL`. I might have mixed up the column positions here, since I don't really understand what those names are meant to represent.

**Edit 2:**

```
string connString = @"database=Agenda_db; Data Source=Marian-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Persist Security Info=false; Integrated Security=SSPI";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Contact", conn))
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(rdr[0].ToString() + " " + rdr[1].ToString() + " " + rdr[2].ToString());
            }
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Numar_contact", conn))
        using (SqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr2.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(rdr2[0].ToString() + " " + rdr2[1].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

**Edit 3, thanks to insight from Scott Chamberlain:**

On the other hand, you might want to perform a [`JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx) of some kind, most commonly an `INNER JOIN`. Note that this is an entirely different operation from any we've talked about before.

```
SELECT Contact.id_contact, Contact.nume_contact, Contact.prenume_contact, Numar_contact.numar
FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Numar_contact on Contact.id_contact = Numar_contact.id_contact
```

This will tie the two tables together, returning a record for each contact-numar_contact. Again, this is definitely *not* the same as doing a `UNION`. Make sure you're aware of the difference before you pick which you want.

Use this if your second table contains data that relates many-to-one to the first table.

Comment: No, it shows me this error: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." !

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code where you state it doesn't work if you really want a clean way of running that code and returning the data why not create as well as execute it in a Stored Procedure..
I know it works as well just created and ran a simple test on my server

Comment: That's why my initial answer included a disclaimer that it depended on the layout of your tables. I've since updated it. List the columns you expect to retrieve explicitly and this should work.

Comment: I don't get it ! I have 2 tables with no relation; first table with the columns (id_contact, nume_contact, prenume_contact) and the second table with two columns (from wich I want to get only one) (the columns are numar and id_contact); I just want to list the 3 columns from first table and the first column from second table (and in both tables, I've inserted only 2 rows)

Comment: So you're adding data from two, unrelated tables into a single listbox? I'd probably pull that into two `SqlCommand`s at that point, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: When you say "two `SqlCommand`s," do you mean two statements in a single `SqlCommand`, like you posed in your question?

Comment: And wait, why is your `foreach` looking at *four* columns, when you just said one table has three and the other, two?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen because he wants a Join of the two tables, not a union.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good call.

Comment: No, I've tried with two SqlCommands with one query each, and I want only one column from the second table.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen The second editing of yours it good, and probabbly I would've done it in that way, but in that way, the results appears as different items of listbox, and I would want in the same item (like a phone book)

Comment: @user3806279 Okay, awesome. So it's definitely decided that you want a join, then. What happens when you execute the last code snippet, from edit three, directly in SSMS without altering it?

Comment: Okay, now copy it, again *exactly* into your code. You can remove the line breaks and substitute in spaces, but don't change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768745/doesnt-work-th-sqlcommand-with-multiple-queries#comment38434382_24768774), what you are wanting to do is [JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx) the tables.

```sql
SELECT Contact.id_contact, nume_contact, prenume_contact, numar
FROM Contact
INNER JOIN Numar_contact on Contact.id_contact = Numar_contact.id_contact
```

That will combine the two tables in to four columns where id_contact matches in both tables.

You may want a `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN` depending on if you want rows to show up only when there is a item in the 2nd table or show up anyway and just make the 4th column `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Error message box: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN' ", and after I close the messagebox, the listbox appears as empty.

Comment: Well that means you screwed up your sql. I would get your query working in Sql Management Studio first then try to use it in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Here is [an example from the MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274) I've modified to use your code - you need to move the reader to the [Next ResultSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string connString = @"database=Agenda_db; Data Source=Marian-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Persist Security Info=false; Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Contact; SELECT * FROM Numar_contact", conn);
SqlDataReader myReader ;

int RecordCount=0; 

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        //Write logic to process data for the first result.
         RecordCount = RecordCount + 1;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Total number of Contacts: " + RecordCount.ToString());

    bool moreResults = myReader.NextResult();   // <<<<<<<<<<< MOVE TO NEXT RESULTSET

    RecordCount = 0;

    while (moreResults && myReader.Read())
    {
        //Write logic to process data for the second result.
        RecordCount = RecordCount + 1;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Total number from Numar_contacts: " + RecordCount.ToString());
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    conn.Close(); // Could be replaced with  using statement too
}
```