# Run multiple SQL Commands on button click EDIT SOLVED

Tags: c#, sql

I have searched here for how to run multiple sql commands on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677318/how-to-run-multiple-sql-commands-in-a-single-sql-connection) and for me it's not clear.

I want to run two SQL queries on button1_click. 1st is delete from table tehnicke_karakteristike where sifra_proizvoda=@sifraProizvoda and 2nd is delete from table proizvod where sifra_proizvoda=@sifraProizvoda. sifra_proizvoda is FK to tehnicke_karakteristike.

Here is my code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       konekcija = new SqlConnection(Konekcija.konString);

        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tehnicke_karakteristike WHERE sifra_proizvoda = @sifra_proizvoda", konekcija);
        SqlParameter sifraParam = new SqlParameter("@sifra_proizvoda", SqlDbType.Int);

        SqlCommand komanda1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM proizvod WHERE sifra_proizvoda = @sifra_proizvoda", konekcija);
        SqlParameter sifraParam1 = new SqlParameter("@sifra_proizvoda", SqlDbType.Int);

        komanda.Parameters.Add(sifraParam);
        komanda1.Parameters.Add(sifraParam1);

        sifraParam.Value = tbSifra.Text;
        sifraParam1.Value = tbSifra.Text;
        try
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
            komanda1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            konekcija.Close();
        }

    }
```

When i run this, only first command pass.

Comment: Some advice: look at "Dapper". Writing ADO.NET code yourself isn't fun, interesting, or useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `komanda1.ExecuteNonQuery()` after `komanda.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which is why only `komanda` gets executed while `komanda1` doesn't.

Also, it's probably a good idea to wrap those 2 commands in a transaction if you're running them like this

Comment: i add that command line after komanda and komanda1 and i get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'

Comment: Think you need to call `connection.Open()`

Comment: @BeginnerCoding is the komanda1 execute inside the try segment?

Comment: @Lucas no it is not

Comment: @BeginnerCoding then it should be. You're closing the connection inside the finally segment that gets executed after the try segment, you want to run both commands before closing the connection

Answer (score 0):

> When i run this, only first command pass.

That is logical: you are executing the query only once:

```
komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Therefore it's the latest assignment that prevails.

You have two queries but a shared parameter, so what you could do is reuse the query by just changing the SQL. If you have an instantiated `SqlCommand` with a connection property, and parameters set, you can change the `CommandText` property and run a different query on that `SqlCommand`.
Not tested but I would try something like this:

```
    SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tehnicke_karakteristike WHERE sifra_proizvoda = @sifra_proizvoda", konekcija);
    SqlParameter sifraParam = new SqlParameter("@sifra_proizvoda", SqlDbType.Int);
    komanda.Parameters.Add(sifraParam);
    sifraParam.Value = tbSifra.Text;

    // execute the 1st statement
    komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // reuse the command
    komanda1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM proizvod WHERE sifra_proizvoda = @sifra_proizvoda"
    // execute the 2nd statement
    komanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That makes the code a bit more compact but you can perfectly define two distinct `SqlCommand` objects - which you did. Then each has to be executed once.