# How can I run multiple SQL commands in one batch using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have quite a few SQL commands that I need to run. I have them in a list and I traverse the list run the SQL command, and then run the next. The issue here is that on every run, the connection is opened and then closed so if there were 50 commands there would be 50 open and close.

The type of command I have are creating functions, tables etc.

Is there an easy way I can do this in C#?

Comment: One of many possible ways are stored procedures ~ they are defined on SQL server you just call it once from C# code. However I would not recommend this approach as in these days there is EntityFramework and instead of SQL queries you can write just C# code that will do that.

Comment: Last, but not least - you do not need to close connection to the SQL server after each command, rather open it once, call all the necessary commands and then close the connection.

Comment: I think the second approach is feasible, but its in a foreach loop so i will need to know when the last statement is and then close connection ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. It might be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677409/7167572

Comment: Show your code. Then refactor it to allow the caller to control the lifetime of the connection. Then consider concatenating the sql command text too.

Comment: Please post an [mcve] of the problem you are having.

Comment: It seems that you're creating an issue out of something that isn't an issue. What issue have you faced such that you believe that opening/closing a connection 50 times is a problem? Are you using Windows 3.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening and closing connections is cheap. [ADO pools connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling). It keeps them open for the next statement that comes along. So when you call `open()`, you get exclusive use of the connection, but `close()` just returns it to the pool.

If you're running multiple statements, concentrate more on things like error handling. You can run multiple statements in one block of SQL, and multiple blocks of SQL one after the other on an open connection. But if one statement fails, do you go on to the next one, or roll back the previous ones, and do you want to manage this in C# or in the SQL. And which statements, if any, return results? These are the factors that should determine where you split your SQL.

It's pretty unusual to create tables in your application code. Have you looked at DB projects ?